# Weka random forest classifier

Tags: weka

I have one problem with choosing a classifier and I will really appreciate if someone could help me with that. I have to use weka J48 decision tree classifier, but I can't find a package in python to for that :/ . therefore, if someone knows where I can find this package or an implementation of this weka decision tree, that will be very helpful for me.